# Meaning of the Sharp Sign in this Mathematica Split Function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, pure-function

I have some problems understanding sharp signs in Mathematica. I understand `# &` as a placeholder for variables. But how are `#1` and `#2` understood in the following code?

```
x = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1};
Split[x, #1 =!= 0 && #2 =!= 0 &]
```

What are `#1` and `#2` here? The output of these lines is

```
{{0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0}, {0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0}, {0}, {1}}
```

Comment: slot is the term https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html

Answer (score 3):

That version of [Split](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html) is of the form `Split[list,test]`, where `test` is a function that takes **two** variables. So

```
#1 =!= 0 && #2 =!= 0 &
```

is shorthand for a two-variable pure function where `#1` and `#2` are the variable names.

---

In general, `Split` will take a list and return the same list partitioned into consecutive runs of "identical" elements. So if your list is `list={0,0,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,7}`, then `Split[list]` yields

```
{{0,0}, {2,2}, {3}, {4,4}, {5,5,5}, {7}}
```

But maybe you want to define what it means for two things to be "identical" differently. That's where the general `Split[list,test]` function comes in. The `test` function here is a function that takes two parameters and returns true if they are identical; the `test` function is *your* test for whether or two things are identical. For example, the test function your gave

```
#1 =!= 0 && #2 =!= 0 &
```

returns true if the two elements are both nonzero. So your `Split` function groups elements if they are a run of zeros, or if they are a run of nonzeros.

For another example, say you want to say two integers are identical if they have the same parity (even or odd). Then your split function would be

```
Split[list, Mod[#1,2] == Mod[#2,2]]
```

which for the list I defined would return

```
{{0,0,2,2}, {3}, {4,4}, {5,5,5,7}}
```